# TypeScript complains when testing the value of array elements after a shift()

Tags: arrays, typescript, typechecking

I have an array of strings, created by a `split` operation on a larger string. I'm doing some testing on the first two elements, like so:

```
var tArray = tLongString.split("_")
if (tArray[0] == "local")
{
    tArray.shift()
    if (tArray[0] == "super") {
       ...
```

Typescript is complaining about the second `if` statement, because it says that I've already checked the value of `tArray[0]` and determined it to be `"local"`, so it can't be `"super"`. But of course in between I've run a `shift()` command, so these aren't actually the same items.

I can solve this by casting `tArray` to `any`, but is there a more Typescript-y solution?

Comment: Code analysis has its limits. Manipulating the array seems to be beyond that limit. You can either use `tArray[0] as string === `  or depending on your target [`tArray.at(0) === `](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at)

Comment: This is a design limitation of TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998). TS "optimistically" assumes that function calls don't mutate state in a way to affect control flow analysis. The "TypeScript-y" solution is not to mutate things if you can help it (e.g., `tArray[1]` instead of `tArray[0]`-after-`tArray.shift()`). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer with sources; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That's a fair answer, @jcalz. Moving the shift inside the if statement would be an obvious solution except that it means I have to do it again in the else. But still, appreciate the thoughts!

Answer (score 2):

This is a longstanding design limitation of TypeScript.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) for a very long and in-depth discussion.

In order to allow [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) to be convenient, the language *optimistically* assumes that function/method calls do not have side effects that would invalidate the control flow analysis.  So the call to `tArray.shift()` is assumed not to invalidate the check that `tArray[0] === "local"`.  This is, of course, a bad assumption.

But there aren't too many viable alternatives.  TypeScript doesn't currently have a way to mark a function as changing the state or what state is changed.  So it can't tell the difference in the type system between `tArray.shift()` (which mutates the array) and `tArray.join()` (which doesn't). The language could *pessimistically* assume that all function calls have the potential to reset control flow narrowings, but then you couldn't write `console.log("hello")` without losing track of the fact that `tArray[0] === "local"`.

So we're kind of stuck with the way it is.

---

That means the "TypeScript-y" solution is to refactor so that you are not modifying any state via function/method calls in an place where you need type guarding to happen.  Instead of accessing `tArray[0]` after a `tArray.shift()`, you could just... *not* modify the array and access `tArray[1]` instead.  The specific refactoring that works best depends strongly on your use cases and the example code in the question isn't quite a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so I wouldn't presume to guess.